# Shipping is not showing in checkout page on magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping

I forgot to put the weight on products, but using bulk action i gave them weight and make it compulsory ...still facing the same problem with old products. and because of this we are also not getting the address information from the customers.
[image]

Comment: try reindexing and recheck after that

Comment: i did but it's not working

Comment: It calculates the shipping once you put in the postal code

Comment: but how it's working fine on new product that we are listing in

Answer (score 1):

Solved : Simply set weight to all virtual product and select option of "This item has weight" in all virtual product also.
because magento gives no weight to virtual products by default, so if you had make virtual product without weight being compulsory and then make weight compulsory due to shipping problems then this kind of problems with products and shipping happens.